# Zend_Validate_inArray - ErrorMessage: non empty value

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

We're using Zend_Filter_Input to validate a Dojo From at Backend. There is "option" Input Element where we have to verify that the submitted value is allowed.

**Problem:** If **nothing** is selected the Zend_Validate_inArray Validator returns

> " you must provide an non Empty value"

thats fine, but we have to change the message. I cant find the proper way to do this..

```
        'FIELD' => array(new Zend_Validate_InArray($allowedValues),
            'messages' => 'MESSAGE_WRONG_VALUE',
            'default'  => ''
         ),
```

Does someone know how to change the "isEmpty" Message?

It is Zend Framework 1.11.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$element->setRequired(true)->addErrorMessage('Your message');
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do this when using Zend Filter Input with array notation

Comment: Are you adding filter for checking nonempty?

Comment: no. Think the problem is: when nothing is selected the field is not submitted at all..

Comment: This will be stop automatically on the method isValid() of the form submit.